# GUI Framework/Lib for C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I was wondering is there an Microsoft alternative to MFC, except WinForms in GUI programming for Windows operating system ?

I dont want to use thirdparty (Borland/Qt/wxWindows) libraries. WinForms require .NET which is major problem (can't install .NET in destination machines) and MFC is traumatic to me...

Any alternative which would be close to Qt but Microsoft branded ?

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I'm curious, why are you so keen on using something that is MS branded? Most people I know would ask for the exact opposite...

Comment: Is there a technical reason you don't want to use non-MS libraries or a preference?

Comment: Client request that all *must* be MS based...

Comment: Why would there be a Microsoft alternative to MFC?  What do you have against MFC?

Comment: try RFC  https://github.com/hasaranga/RFC-Framework

Answer (score 16):

I too suggest WTL. Here is a list with some useful WTL links:

- MSDN's [ATL 3.0 Window Classes: An Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260759%28VS.60%29.aspx) - for the basics.
- WTL Articles by Chris Sells, Dharma Shukla, and Nenad Stefanovic [part1](http://sellsbrothers.com/writing/wtlpart1.zip) and [part2](http://sellsbrothers.com/writing/wtlpart2.zip). Nenad Stefanovic is the father of WTL.
- Bjarke Viksoe's [WTL projects](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/all_wtl.htm). Bjarne has summed many of his small projects into a whole application, an IDE - [BVRDE](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/bvrde.htm).
- Code Project's [WTL page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/). Watch out especially the articles written by [Michael Dunn](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=152). VMware Workstation uses WTL and Michael Dunn works for VMware.
- Clipcode's WTL Developer’s Guide ([doc](http://code.assembla.com/cristianadam/subversion/node/blob/WTL%20Developer%27s%20Guide/WTL_Developer%27s_Guide.doc), [pdf](http://code.assembla.com/cristianadam/subversion/node/blob/WTL%20Developer%27s%20Guide/WTL_Developer%27s_Guide.pdf), [source code](http://code.assembla.com/cristianadam/subversion/node/blob/WTL%20Developer%27s%20Guide/WTL_Developer%27s_Guide_source_code.zip)).

WTL opensource applications, which one can study to see various implementation tricks:

- Google's Chromium, source code [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/). The windows version uses WTL. I don't know if somebody has tried to extract the WTL framework from Chromium.
- [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) uses WTL, source code [here](http://pnotepad.googlecode.com/svn/).
- [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) uses WTL, source code [here](https://infrarecorder.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/infrarecorder/).

Comment: +1 for the excellent plethora of information regarding your suggestion, the OP should mark an answer, as the question is old. Seems like the OP got discouraged and forgot this is SO.

Answer (score 10):

Try [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/). This library was originally created by Microsoft and then went open source. On the contrary with MFC, many developers report good experiences with it. It builds lighter executables, it is better structured than MFC, but also not so feature rich.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any. You can use pure WinAPI, ATL, [WTL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5BA5BA4-6E6B-462A-B24C-61115E846F0C&displaylang=en) (in this case good luck!).

Why don't you want to use Qt? Its free, open source and very flexible tool.

Comment: Why - client request for MS only technology/libs and resources

Answer (score 1):

Although I love it and have used it extensively, WTL is quite an effort to learn as the documentation isn't great.  There are some great '[WTL for MFC Programmers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc1.aspx)' articles on Code Project which are an absolute must-read.

However, if you want something Qt-like from MS, then you're only left with MFC I'm afraid.  OK, it's long in the tooth but with the addition of the VS2008 SP1 [MFC Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982354.aspx) you can create Office 2007-like apps complete with ribbons.  This might be your best solution if only MS non-.NET tech is allowed.

Comment: unfortunately, certain mfc classes use .net .. *sighs*

Answer (score 0):

There is not any. Do not waste your time for searching.

Comment: WTL download link from the MS servers:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=48cb01d7-112e-46c2-bb6e-5bb2fe20e626&displaylang=en

(BTW it wasn't me who downvoted you)

Comment: I think this is a good response - there is really no MS library other than MFC which would be "close to Qt". WTL is great, but it is not an application framework like Qt or MFC.

Comment: I agree - WTL is not an app framework and the lack of decent docs makes the learning curve very steep.

Comment: -1 because this is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Any alternative which would be close to Qt but Microsoft branded

If by "close to Qt" you mean similar in design to Qt, then no - there is not. I use WTL and like it, but it is very different from Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go with the Windows API directly and bypass MFC.

Comment: Ewwww.  We've got one program here that uses the straight Win32 API, and I'm the primary maintainer.  I'd like to know what the API designers were smoking, and where I can get some.

Comment: @DavidThornley The api designers were not smoking anything. The only way for two components with different ABI's to talk to each other in a NON managed manner (there's 2) is a flat C interface (aka windows api), and COM <~ yea.. that one did not exist when the api was created. And considering what all depends on the api (MFC, ATL, And every single application/framework you can think of) their not too keen on breaking the world by just changing it. Which, of course, they should.

Comment: @johnathon:  I understand why they'd need to keep it that way, once first released.  However, I've seen good flat C interfaces before, and that didn't look to qualify to me.

Comment: @DavidThornley I'm not disagreeing with you on the fact that the api is not as 'pretty' as it should be. But you also have to think of the state of compilers at the time as well. They did not have access to the compiler technologies we have today. I do not envy the developers that implemented the api, as it is the ONE thing Microsoft still gets scorned for, the one thing they cannot get away from. With all that said though, once you get the conventions of using the api down, it's not THAT horrible. And in truth, I have seen much worse.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get it. If it isn't Win32 or MFC or Windows.Forms, then what you are looking for is by definition 3rd party.

All these people recommending WTL are recommending you download some third party project's toolkit and use it. That's fine, if that's what you are looking for. But if you do that, then I strongly suggest looking at Qt or wxWidget. The former for the most full-featured set you can get and the latter for drawing native widgets using a "more sane" API.

Aside: WTL may be downloadable from MS server, but its a far, far cry from a MS-supported technology. It is an unsupported add-on.

Comment: Still, WTL can be presented to his customers as a "MS technology". It was originally developed by MS, and is being used within MS, and also Google, VMWare and other big software companies.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. It was developed by Nenad Stefanovic, who was a Microsoft employee at the time. It was never a "Microsoft technology" though. People often assume that if something is released by a MS team on MS Servers then that means that its an official MS-supported technology. It isn't. And in many companies where MS only counts, the distinction is a very important one.

Comment: I am not saying it is supported by MS, but it was ceirtanly not a Nenad's free-time project, but a Microsoft product. It was first released as a part of Microsoft's SDK, and it was Microsoft that released it under an open-source license (crafted by Microsoft's lawyers).

Comment: @Shaun what Nemanja Trifunovic said.